# Why do I get a typeorder for str and int here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My assignment is:

> Write a program to fetch employee  name and the salary.  Calculate the
>   Federal tax and state tax based on the following criteria:   If the
>   salary is greater than 100000 then calculate the federal tax at 20%
>   otherwise calculate the federal tax at 15%   Calculate the state tax
>   at 5%   Calculate the net salary of the employee. To calculate the net
>   salary, subtract federal and state tax from the gross salary.

My code:

```
employeename = input("Enter the employee's name:")
grosssalary = input("Enter the employee's gross salary: $")
if grosssalary > 100000:
    federaltax = 0.20
else:
    federaltax = 0.15
statetax = 0.05
netsalary = float(grosssalary) - float(grosssalary * federaltax) - float(grosssalary * statetax)
print (employeename,"'s net salary is $",netsalary)
```

The output:

```
Enter the employee's name:Ali
Enter the employee's gross salary: $1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Untitled4", line 3, in <module>
    if grosssalary > 100000:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
Process exited with code: 1
```

Comment: You should first convert your string into int.

Comment: this is a duplicate for sure...

Answer (score 1):

[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns type `str` in Python 3.x.

So you are doing `grosssalary > 100000` which is `str > int`.

To solve, use:

```
gross_salary = int(input("Enter the employee's gross salary: $"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x, return value of [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is always of type `str`, so you are comparing a `str` object to an `int` object, which yields a TypeError. You cannot do that, you have to convert it to `int` or `float` before comparison.

Try this:

```
grosssalary = float(input("Enter the employee's gross salary: $"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, That you try to check if a string is greater than an int and that is not acceptable.

You should first convert your string into int and then make your check, your code should looks like:

```
employeename = input("Enter the employee's name:")
grosssalary = input("Enter the employee's gross salary: $")
if int(grosssalary) > 100000:
    federaltax = 0.20
else:
    federaltax = 0.15
statetax = 0.05
netsalary = float(grosssalary) - float(grosssalary * federaltax) - float(grosssalary * statetax)
print (employeename,"'s net salary is $",netsalary)
```

And you should also check first if the string is an int, To do that your check should looks like:

```
if grosssalary.isdigit()

    if int(grosssalary) > 100000:

        federaltax = 0.20
    else:
        federaltax = 0.15
else:
    print("bad entry")
```